# Create default config for each tenant in C#

Tags: c#, config, default

I have basic CRUD for a class ConfigSystem.

I have also two methods in the basic ConfigSystem Service.

```
    public Type Get<Type>(string key, string userId)
    {
        //get config system
        var configEntry = this.repository.GetSingleAsync(cs => cs.Key == key && cs.UserId == userId).Await();
        if (configEntry == null)
        {
            configEntry = this.repository.GetSingleAsync(cs => cs.Key == key).Await();
        }
        if (typeof(Type).Name == configEntry.Type)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type>(configEntry.Value);

            //invalid config type exception
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException($"Cannot get the type of this particular key! ");
        }
    }

    public async Task Set<T>(string key, string userId, T value)
    {
        CheckKey(key, userId);
        // find key and then update its value
        var configEntry = await this.repository.GetSingleAsync(cs => cs.Key == key && cs.UserId == userId);
        //configEntry.Key = key;

        if (configEntry == null)
        {
            configEntry = await this.repository.GetSingleAsync(cs => cs.Key == key);
        }

        configEntry.Type = value.GetType().Name;
        configEntry.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        await this.repository.UpdateAsync(configEntry);
    }
```

I have a static file Config:

```
 public static Dictionary<string, object> ConfigurationList = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"Currency", Enums.Currency.Lev },
            {"Measure", Enums.Unit.LinearMetre },
            {"DailyDraftLimit", 6},
            {"DeleteDraftPeriod", 5},
            {"NotificationStartTime", new TimeSpan(03, 00, 00) }, //give exact time 3AM.},
            //TODO: Exclude weekends 
            {"NotificationPeriod", 24},//24 hours
            {"PaymentNotificationPeriod", 24},
            {"PaymentReceivers", null}, //what do I put here? if I dont have the ids/ -> we put null if we are not sure about the info or the info is not static!
            {"VisitsNotificationPeriod", 24},
            {"VisitsInternalReceivers", null},
            {"VisitsExternalReceivers", null},
            {"TermsNotificationPeriod", 24},
            {"TermsReceivers", null }
}
```

and this is my ConfigSystem class:

```
public class ConfigSystem : AuditEntity<long>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the key.
    /// </summary>

    public string Key { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the type.
    /// </summary>
    public string Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value.
    /// </summary>
    public string Value { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user identifier.
    /// </summary>
    public string UserId { get; set; }

}
```

This is my method in the Startup.

```
    private void CreateDefaultConfig(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceScope serviceScope)
    {
        var defaultConfig = DefaultTenantConfig.ConfigurationList;
        if (context.ConfigSystems.Count() == 0)
        {
            var configSystemService = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfigSystemService>();

            //foreach (var entry in defaultConfig)
            //{
            //    var entityToSaveInDb = configSystemService.CreateAsync()
            //}
            //create for each record a config system entry in the database
        }
        //check if in the context of the database there are no configs

    }
```

I have no idea what to do with the object, but I had to keep it in object because I had different type of entries. I need to create them for each tenant and it is a default config if they are not created in the database.

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question - create for each record a config system entry in the database

Comment: so you would like to Get default config from database, but first you must fill your database with it in migration? Is It your scenario?

Comment: I had to use the DbContext and work with it. I was going on the wrong direction by using the service provider.

Comment: Do not make CRUD operations in Startup. If there will be an error or bug it is difficult to detect and your Web App will not start. You'd better make migration. But the best idea is to save configs in config files (injected during deployment) or GET them from some kind of secure storage like Azure key vault